# If there is no Internet connection, program crashes

Tags: .net, vb.net, webclient

My program works perfectly, however, if there is no internet connection, it crashes.(Errors this: blabla stopped working)

My program exe

```
Module module2


    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.example.org")
    Dim oza As Object


    Sub main()

        oza = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        oza.Navigate2("http://www.example.org", "", "", "")

End Sub

End Module
```

How to prevent the program from crash ?

Comment: An Exception was thrown, no? - See [Handling and Throwing Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b2yeyab%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Couldn't understand what you mean.

Comment: Well, for instance, if [`DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throws a *WebException* (because it could not download the file because the internet is not available) then the program, which doesn't handle the exception gracefully, will terminate "abnormally". See the link in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

[WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throws a WebException when the resource cannot be downloaded - such as when there is no internet access. Since this exception is not gracefully handled the program "crashes".

See [Handling and Throwing Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b2yeyab%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for how to deal with this situation, and note:

> An exception is thrown from an area of code where a problem has occurred. The exception is passed up the stack until the application handles it or the program terminates.

Such problems can be diagnosed easily by [attaching the debugger or "running with F5"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), which allows monitoring of thrown exceptions.